# css3 having a buggy 'ghosting' on this effect?

Tags: html, animation, css

unforunately i cant reproduce it in jsfiddle...... heres my code though regardless: http://jsfiddle.net/nZePr/

basically when you hover over a tooldtip, it leaves a very faint ghost of about 5% opacity and it doesnt fade out 100%. can you guys see anything wrong with my code? this is what it looks like:

You can see the very faint outline of it bugging out.

[image: ghost effect]

Comment: Probably a beta issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem is exaggerated if you try to animate too much in a very small increment. i moved the distance that the tooltip has to travel a few more pixels and it also cleared it up. also reducing the time by .1s also helped. it has it about 1% now but its so hard to see that its all good to go :)